# Laravel create migration file in specific folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, migration, laravel-artisan

I've created Payment package for my laravel project[image: like here]

I want to make migration files inside migrations folder of my package. How can create it using artisan command?
I want something like

```
php artisan make:migration packages/Payment/src/Database/add_orderId_to_cart_payment_table
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use this command on the root folder:

create the only Migration file:

```
php artisan make:migration create_products_table --create=products
```

Create Migration, Model file:

```
php artisan make:model Product -m
```

For Create Migration,Model,Controller file:

```
php artisan make:model Product -mcr
```

If you want to do it manually then you may set `--path` as per your folder requirement.

```
php artisan make:migration filename --path=/app/database/migrations/relations
php artisan make:migration filename --path=/app/database/migrations/translations
```

If you want to migrate then:

```
php artisan migrate --path="/app/database/migrations/relations"
```

Answer (score 8):

**For specific directories:**

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table --path=/packages/Payment/src/Database
```

The new migration will be placed in your ***`packages/Payment/src/Database`*** directory.

For Running Migrations: `php artisan migrate --path=/packages/Payment/src/Database`

---

**Generating a migration using the inbuilt framework feature:**

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table
```

The new migration will be placed in your ***`database/migrations`*** directory.

For Running Migrations: `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 3):

you need to publish them from your package to your migrations folder like this in your package service provider boot method:

```
  $this->publishes([
        __DIR__.'/Database/migrations/' => database_path('migrations'),
    ], 'migrations');
```

run this command `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=migrations`

and after that you can run `php artisan migrate`

Comment: I know how to publish and migrate. I want to make, create migration file

Comment: Migrations do not need to be published, they are resources like flags of all the countries, seeders etc. Migrations are automatically run when a package user run migrations, there is a method `loadMigrationsFrom()`, it takes the path where actually package's migrations are located, when package user migrations, all the migrations run, whether they are created by user or by the package @merdan

Answer (score 1):

You can run:

`php artisan make:migration --help` and see all the options available for you to use.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're creating a package and you're wondering how to handle database migrations. One way to do this is to create the migrations in the usual way, using the `php artisan make:migration` command, and then running the migrations to create the necessary tables and structure.

Once you have created and run the migrations, you can include them in your package by placing them in the `src/Database/migrations` directory of your package. This will allow the migrations to be loaded and run when the package is installed and the php artisan migrate command is run.

To ensure that the migrations are loaded and run correctly, you will need to include the following line in the `boot()` method of your package's service provider:

```php
$this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__ . '/Database/migrations');
```

This will tell Laravel to load the migrations from the src/Database/migrations directory of your package.

It's important to note that the `loadMigrationsFrom()` method is a built-in feature of Laravel, and it will allow the migrations to be run regardless of whether they are located in the user's `Database/migrations` directory or in your package's `src/Database/migrations` directory. This will ensure that the migrations are run correctly when the package is installed and the php artisan migrate command is run.