# How to create a new migration file under laravel-modules?

Tags: laravel

reading how laravel-modules works for laravel 6
https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v6/advanced-tools/artisan-commands

I did not find how to create a new migration file. I tried 2 ways and failed both :

```
root@95e2f26acdf8:/app/Modules/Opportunities# php artisan make:migration leads_table_add_test_id_fields --table=leads
Could not open input file: artisan
root@95e2f26acdf8:/app/Modules/Opportunities# php artisan make:migration Opportunities leads_table_add_test_id_fields --table=leads
Could not open input file: artisan


root@95e2f26acdf8:/app/Modules/Opportunities# cd ../
root@95e2f26acdf8:/app/Modules# cd ../
root@95e2f26acdf8:/app# php artisan make:migration Opportunities leads_table_add_test_id_fields --table=leads
  Too many arguments, expected arguments "command" "name".
```

**MODIFIED** :

Yes, that command

```
php artisan module:make-migration leads_table_add_test_fields Opportunities
```

works ok. But I tried to add --table= option as

```
php artisan module:make-migration leads_table_add_test_fields  Opportunities --table=opportunities
```

but got error :

```
 The "--table" option does not exist.
```

?

Which way is correct ?

Comment: php artisan module:make-migration module_name, please read all the docs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57230550/9978078 please check this answer to create new migration in specific folder.

Comment: Please look at MODIFIED

Comment: nwidart doesnt support extra commands for migration as i read it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should run:

```
php artisan module:make-migration add_field_to_leads_table Opportunities
```